# Using a string as a name for a numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy-ndarray, data-conversion

I have a list including some names, as example:
`data_set_names=['matrix_1','matrix_2','matrix_3']`.
Inside a loop, I want to use each of these names for storing the output of some computations, which are as NumPy array. I highly appreciate if someone could tell me how to do that. As I looked it up online, `exec()` function can be used to convert a string to a variable name, but in my case, it is not useful.

Comment: Would storing the matrices as values in a dictionary where the keys are the strings in the list work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about using `globals()` or `locals()` depending on your needs. Both are a dictionary of the variables you are using in your code, (global or locals) and from there you can assign a variable as a string, in your case something like:

```
for i in data_set_names:
    globals()[i] = 'your data here'
```

Comment: So why not use an explicit dictionary rather than doing this weird stuff?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, as I tried using a Dictionary is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dictionary` of `str/numpyArray`